# Get next birthdays using Doctrine

Tags: doctrine

Is there any way to get the next birthdays using only DQL (Doctrine Query Language)?

I have solved the problem using the SQL function `DAYOFYEAR`, but I would like to have a DQL solution, in case I need to migrate to MSSQL (for example) where this doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by next birthdays?

Comment: For the current week, get all the birthdays from my customers. Something like Facebook does for all the friends.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the function from MySQL. Simply use PHP's [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function and use format "z". Quoting the PHP docs:

> z -> The day of the year (starting from 0) -> 0 through 365

Alternatively, you can also use [strftime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) with "%j" (or anything else that suits you)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to get upcoming birthdays by using native query in doctrine.
This is a quick query and according to http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html Doctrine uses ResultSetMapping the same way internally when you create DQL queries.

This finds all the birthdays the next 30 days.

Use this method with care since it will affect how the entity is loaded later. Later in the script, only those fields added to the mapping will be loaded for this entity. I loaded the list by ajax ( and addded it to session )

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult('AppBundle:User', 'u');
$rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'id', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'firstname', 'firstname');
$rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'lastname', 'lastname');
$rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'birthday', 'birthday');
$rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'image', 'image');

$query = $this->entityManager->createNativeQuery("
        SELECT * 
        FROM user u 
        WHERE DAYOFYEAR(u.birthday) 
        BETWEEN DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) AND DAYOFYEAR(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL ? DAY))
        ORDER BY DAYOFYEAR(u.birthday) ASC
        ", $rsm);

$query->setParameter(1, '30');

$birthdays = $query->getResult();
```